# Reshape group labels in ggradar

Tags: r, dplyr

When using `ggradar` long variable names don't fit the pane. Is there a way to reshape the variable names in `ggradar`?

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggradar)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "C"),
  variable_with_long_name_1 = c(0,1,0.5),
  variable_with_long_name_2 = c(0,1,.5),
  variable_with_long_name_3 = c(1,0,0.5)
)
ggradar(data)
```

This works and looks something like:

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually straight forward. `ggradar` allows to scale all labels:

- Variable names are scaled by setting the `axis.label.size` option,
- the scale labels by setting `grid.label.size` option and
- the legend by setting the `legend.label.size` option.

So

```
library(ggradar)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "C"),
  variable_with_long_name_1 = c(0,1,0.5),
  variable_with_long_name_2 = c(0,1,.5),
  variable_with_long_name_3 = c(1,0,0.5)
)

ggradar(data, axis.label.size = 3, grid.label.size = 3, legend.text.size = 10)
```

plots to something like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I may, I suggest the use of [`ggRadar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggiraphExtra/versions/0.2.9/topics/ggRadar) from `ggiraphExtra`:

```
library(ggiraphExtra)

g <- ggRadar(data, aes(color = group), scales = "free") + 
theme_minimal() +
theme(text = element_text(size=7), # custom font size
    axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Plus you'll get to use the `ggplot2` grammar.

Also I think it's better to use the simple `ggsave`, just play around with the dimension, you won't have to sacrifice text size:

```
g <- ggRadar(data, aes(color = group), scales = "free") + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
print(g)
ggsave("/plt.png", width = 16, height = 9, dpi = 120)
```

Data used:

```
data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "C"),
  variable_with_long_name_1 = c(0,1,0.5),
  variable_with_long_name_2 = c(0,1,.5),
  variable_with_long_name_3 = c(1,0,0.5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggradar)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "C"),
  "variable with long name"= c(0,1,0.5),
  "variable with \n long name" = c(0,1,.5),
  variable_with_long_name_3 = c(1,0,0.5)
)
ggradar(data)+
  ggtitle("Title on \n two lines")
```

with other ggplot features I used "\n" inside long labels (like titles or names), but with ggradar it does not work. Maybe you can still use this as a hint to change something

Answer (score 0):

Another method which might work, at least if you only have a few categories in your spider chart:

Add the text to the front of the graph, as indicated by Joachim Schork in the link below

https://statisticsglobe.com/add-bold-and-italic-text-to-ggplot2-plot-in-r

```
ggp +                               # Add bold text element to plot, could be anything else like italic
annotate("text", x = 4.5, y = 2.2, size = 5,
       label = "My Bold Text",
       fontface = "bold")
```

Comment: Please merge this into your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but for me rescaling the label was not an option (readability). As the goal was to not have the labels clipped though, here is the solution i found:

There is the option **plot.extent.x.sf** which can be increased to extend the size of the plot horizontally. I set it to 2, and then also my longest feature label was plotted correctly.